# Regex that matches when item is mid-string or end string

Tags: regex

Using regex in IIS Url Rewrite (Microsoft)

I am trying to write a regex which will capture companyname/company-name only in any of the following:

get-involved/companies/company-name-2

get-involved/companies/company-name

get-involved/companies/companyname-5

get-involved/companies/companyname

*So to be clear I want to capture just a variable companyname that may or may not have a trailing `-[0-9]` BUT I dont want the trailing `-[0-9]`*

I have the following but its not right as it includes the `-2` when it is present

```
get-involved/companies/((.*)|((.*)(-[0-9])))
```

Comment: What about `get-involved\/companies\/(.*?)(-[0-9])?$` -> https://regex101.com/r/hP7zN4/1

Comment: (1) As always with regex questions, please specify the language or tool you’re using, because we are in a maze of twisty little regex specifications, all slightly different. (2) Are you trying to capture a literal string `company-?name`, or just whatever’s before a hyphen and digit, or what?

Comment: Using regex in IIS Url Rewrite (Microsoft).  I want to capture just  company-name or companyname but not the -[0-9]

Comment: Also am not trying to capture a literal string but a variable company name that may have a trailing -[0-9]

Answer (score 0):

*This answer will work with JS or PHP, but as noticed by @Tom Zych, some little specifications may be different with IIS Url Rewrite, that I don't use: so it's up to you to check.*

That's said, you can use the followin regexp:

```
^get-involved/companies/([^-]*)-?([^-]*)?(?:-[0-9])$
```

then use the following replacement:
`$1$2`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
get-involved\/companies\/(?:(.+(?=-[0-9]))|(.+\b))
```

Basically the main idea is to use *alternation* in a *non-capturing* group. The first alternative matches any phrase which ends with -[0-9] using a positive lookahead and the second one matches anything until it reaches a word boundary (or you may use end of string anchor).

You can test it using [regex101](https://regex101.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify that a hyphen needs to be followed by an alphabetic.

```
get-involved/companies/([^/-]+(-[a-z][^/-]+)*)
```

If you have a company name like `3com` this will not work correctly; maybe update your question with more detailed requirements in that case.